# ad-hoc deployment with xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, adhoc, cyberduck

i want to test my own app on my iphone. I saw a video tutorial in youtube and so i shared my app to my device. But however, it doesnt work. The app is running correctly in the simulator (version 5.0,5.1,6). But on my device, it is crashing and the app terminates.

i have done the following steps:

creating .ipa:

Product -> Archive -> Distribute -> Enterprise & Ad-hic deployment -> dont re-sign

sync in itunes:

after saving the ipa, i drag it into itunes to sync. Then im draging it out of itunes.

ssh with cyberduck:

i can connect correctly with cyberduck. i share the ipa file in the "downloads" folder from installous and after sharing, i am installing it manually (from the iphone). (appsync 5.0+ is installed)

But then, when i want to start the app, it is starting for a second and then it crashes. The app terminate and kicks me to the home screen.

did i missed something?

i am using:

xcode 4.5.2
cyberduck
itunes 11.0.1

note: excuse my english please :)

Comment: can you post the crash log? The [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) can help you to get it. Another option is plug the iPhone to your development machine and in Xcode select to run the app on the device

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Don't Resign use your valid adhoc profile same as below image:

[image]

& then check.

Comment: i can only choose "Don't resign" and "Refresh code signing identity..." How can i create a valid adhoc profile/certificate?

Comment: You should first make adhoc provisioning profile in https://developer.apple.com/ then it is appear in your target as I show you in my image...

Comment: See this link & understand hoe to make & prepare your app for adhoc submission: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Comment: Also see this link: http://www.flynax.com/iphone-ipod-app/create-apple-account-instruction.html

Comment: i cant create a ios provisioning profile. Everytime, when i want to access this page with my profile: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action, i get a message with "access denied; You do not have access to the page you requested."

im not in the (payed) developer program of apple. should i have to be a payed member?

Comment: If you have not paid account then how you create provisioning profile of adhoc...& because of this reason you are not able to distribute your App to your user or client...